# Python doesn't recognise pandas even though installed

Tags: python, pandas, module

I have installed pandas with pip. I tried to fix this problem so i checked if some people also have this problem on the internet. A lot of people do. The problem is, I don't have much experience with coding and most answers people gave, i could not make sense of. Can someone give me a thorough help on what to do. I also have the same problem with pygame module and i think they share the root cause. I am on python 3.10.1

I simply wanted to test if the module works

Comment: Try using `pip3` instead of `pip`.

Comment: you may have two Pythons installed but Pythons don't share modules. You installed module in one Python but you run code with other Python. You may also check versions `pip -V` and `python -V` to confirm it. If you run `python script.py` then use also `python -m pip install ..` to install module in correct Python.

Comment: you may also do in code `import sys` and `print( sys.executable )` to get `/full/path/to/python` and in console use `/full/path/to/python -m pip install ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 2 or more than 2 python versions installed as system interpreters this error could happen. I had problem like this when I had 3 versions(3.9, 3.8, 2.7) of python and I tried installing numpy. NumPy was automatically installed for python 3.8 but I was using 3.9 as interpreter. Solution is when installing a module first see what version you're using to code than give clear command to pip. So instead of just

```
pip install pandas
```

Try giving version too

```
python3.9 -m pip install pandas
```